# Add HTTPS "layer" to Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, ssl, https, azure-container-instances

I'm running InfluxDB in Azure Container Instance. Influx has capabilities to enable HTTPS, however I'm looking for some service in Azure that will make it easier for me to manage certificates. With Influx built-in HTTPS support, I'd have to deploy the certificate to the Azure Storage Account's File Share periodically (before cert expiration). That doesn't seem "elegant". Is there some other Azure service that could be used instead? I imagine it would be a kind of layer on top of my container that would just act as a proxy between users and my container, adding HTTPS support.

I saw https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl, however I do not know how to manage certificates on secret volumes. How to change certificate when one expires?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Azure App Service for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker) for this. It comes with built-in SSL certificates and lots of other goodies which you don't get with Container Instances - at a higher cost.

```
az webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan --name <app-name> --deployment-container-image-name influxdb:latest
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container) for more config options such as persistent storage.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Surely I'll check this out

Comment: I see one problem - mounting volumes. I need that functionality to persist influx data in case of problems. Webapps have this feature, however it's in preview (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage) and shouldn't be used on production.

Comment: While I won't tell you the opposite, you can consider that the feature has been already been announced in preview a while ago, so it *should* already have matured quite a bit (https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/09/24/Announcing-Bring-your-own-Storage-to-App-Service.html)